Why does a double dash (--) cause this MariaDB clause to evaluate as true?
As part of our introduction to computer security course, we have a short unit on SQL injections. One of the homework assignments is a basic unsanitized login page. The expected solution is something along the lines of the classic ' or 1=1; -- , but we always welcome students to find unconventional solutions.
One such solution was presented to me recently: inputting '--' for the password seems to perform a successful SQL injection. This would cause the query to be evaluated as something like:
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='admin' AND password=''--'';
Here, --''; is not parsed as a comment, since MariaDB requires that comments are followed by spaces. In fact, if the double dash was parsed as a comment, this query wouldn't return anything at all; equivalently we would have password='', which would evaluate to false, assuming a non-empty password.
The extra pair of quotes at the end appears to be necessary: leaving it as password=''--; or inserting other data behind it (password=''--1;) causes the conditional to be evaluated as false, as expected.
Some quick testing fails to reproduce this behavior in other databases -- as far as I can tell, this is MariaDB-specific behavior. The documentation confirms that two dashes without a space are not parsed as a comment, but does not elaborate on what they are parsed as instead. EDIT: Somehow I managed to miss the fact that this happens in MySQL too. In fact, this behavior occurs in any MySQL fork (not just MariaDB).
What does -- do when it is not followed by a space, and why it causing comparisons to evaluate as true?
A toy example:
CREATE TABLE users (
  userid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  username TEXT NOT NULL,
  password TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES (0001, 'admin', 'S3cur3P4ssw0rd!');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (0002, 'generic_user', 'Password');

SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='admin' AND password=''; -- empty password, query returns no users
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='admin' AND password=''-- ''; -- parsed as comment, equivalent to above query, returns no users
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='admin' AND password=''--''; -- query returns admin user
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='admin' AND password=''--; -- query returns zero users
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='admin' AND password=''--1; -- query returns zero users


"... a basic unsanitized login page." - Please note that "sanitization" is not the defense against SQL injection; the defense is not embedding user input in SQL queries in an unsafe way. For example, by using parameterized SQL queries. See this answer for a more elaborate explanation.

@marcelm Certainly parameterization is the ideal mitigation, but if we parameterized everything then students wouldn’t exactly be able to practice SQL injections, would they ;) I mention sanitization more to establish the context (e.g. there are no string replacements that could cause this), but of course this is tangential to the core question and I can edit for clarity, if that’s something you think needs clarification.

@marcelm: "not [...] in an unsafe way" The way of making something unsafe safe is a form of sanitization. Not all forms of sanitization are SQL injection protections, but SQL injection protection (as it relates to user input values) is a form of sanitization.

@Flater I disagree completely. Sanitization is widely understood as modifying input data to somehow make it "safe". This is different from keeping the data as-is, but handling it in such a way that it poses no threat (e.g. using parametrized SQL queries). That's the entire point of the answer I linked.

@marcelm: You are aware that parametrization still sanitizes certain values which would otherwise just as easily be injected through a parameter, right? At some point, your string value needs to get into the query, and a string-based parameter is not going to stop injection tomfoolery if you don't also remove the harmful contents of said string. The point of advocating for paramterization is (a) good practice and (b) because it comes with sanitization out of the box, which is better than trying to roll your own.

This specific SQL injection uses two aspects:
First, -- without the space, together with a value behind it, is parsed as a subtraction of a negative number. When you run the query
SELECT '10'--'9'

You will get the following result:
+-----------+
| '10'--'9' |  //Interpreted as 10 minus -9 (negating the negative)
+-----------+
|        19 |
+-----------+

So when you run the query
SELECT ''--''

You get the result of the first number (0) minus the negative second number (-0), which results in 0.
+--------+
| ''--'' |
+--------+
|      0 |
+--------+

The second part is that MariaDB (and MySQL) tries to convert a string to a number when the current context requires the value to be a number (like in arithmetic or in numeric comparison, where one operand is already numeric). See the following query:
SELECT 'some value', '42 apples';

This results in nothing special:
+------------+-----------+
| some value | 42 apples |
+------------+-----------+
| some value | 42 apples |
+------------+-----------+

but when you do arithmetic like this
SELECT 'some value'+0, '42 apples'+0;

you get this:
+----------------+---------------+
| 'some value'+0 | '42 apples'+0 |
+----------------+---------------+
|              0 |            42 |
+----------------+---------------+

This can be used against you with the arithmetic above with a value that results in 0. The query
SELECT password, ''--'', password+0, password=0, password=''--'' FROM users;

will show the following results (I added a new user with a number at the beginning of the password):
+-----------------+--------+------------+------------+-----------------+
| password        | ''--'' | password+0 | password=0 | password=''--'' |
+-----------------+--------+------------+------------+-----------------+
| S3cur3P4ssw0rd! |      0 |          0 |          1 |               1 |
| Password        |      0 |          0 |          1 |               1 |
| 42 apples       |      0 |         42 |          0 |               0 |
+-----------------+--------+------------+------------+-----------------+

Here you see, it will first convert the password to a number, most likely 0, and then compare it against "your" 0 value from ''--'', resulting in a successful SQL injection.

Interesting. I suspected that MariaDB might have been doing some kind of casting, but didn't make the connection between -- and a subtraction. Thanks for the quick answer!

Does this mean that (assuming the injection is possible) if using ''--'' the check fails you can deduct that the password starts with a number?

@JohnDoe not quite, it could be . followed by a number.

@ysth: You're confusing numbers with digits.  .123 is a number just as much as 0.123 is (and with the same value). So a password like .123apple starts with a number, even though it does not start with a digit. The fact that MariaDB will fail the injection here means that MariaDB itself considers .123apple to start with a number (i.e. a value it can parse numerically).
